# ReactNative - Attempted to assign to readonly property

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to run simple react native code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ExchangeApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

But it fails:

[image]

```
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "0.50.3"
```

Comment: Is your component name is different than what you have created? Trying to register component with a different name than the created one gives error but I'm not sure if this is related to that.

Comment: Can you try it with the latest libraries , delete the `node_modules` folder and then do an `npm/yarn install` `"react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4"`

Comment: @JudeFernandes I found the problem was in these methods: `function resetCurrentFiber() {return;
        ReactDebugCurrentFrame.getCurrentStack = null, ReactDebugCurrentFiber$2.current = null, 
        ReactDebugCurrentFiber$2.phase = null;
    }
    function setCurrentFiber(fiber) {return;
        ReactDebugCurrentFrame.getCurrentStack = getCurrentFiberStackAddendum, ReactDebugCurrentFiber$2.current = fiber, 
        ReactDebugCurrentFiber$2.phase = null;
    }
    function setCurrentPhase(phase) {return;
        ReactDebugCurrentFiber$2.phase = phase;
    }` fixed the problem.

Comment: @JudeFernandes but of course it's not a solution, trying to update libraries.

Comment: @karaxuna Considering I did not face it while using a newer version of the library I'm assuming its fixed but you should definitely report it to the react team, it seems like a bug